# When skipping an audit in Late Answers, going back in your browser allows you to see others' outcomes on the audit, instead of letting you redo it

Tags: bug, review-queues, review-audits, triage

When skipping an audit in Late Answers, going back in your browser allows you to see if others passed or failed the audit, instead of letting you redo it. On normal reviews, if you use "Skip" and go back in your browser, it lets you still do the review.

This is not the case in Triage or First Posts (it allows you to still do the audit), just a Late Answers specific thing.

Comment: I just found one but couldn't reproduce. I pressed Skip, then Back, then voted and passed the audit. Can you encounter it again to ensure it wasn't a one-off thing?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I tried it again, but was not able to reproduce it. Maybe it only happens when someone else has already done the audit? I'd already encountered it twice on subsequent audits before posting this question.